# Simple Date Format With TimeZone Issue

Tags: java

Hi i have problem with simpledateformat+ timezone here is my code and i am expecting my output as 25/11/2011 but its returning as 24/11/2011. And my current time zone is Pacific and i am testing this on (25/11/2011).
Please help.

Hi Please find the complete program i am not just printing it i am comparing with current date and i was expecting the output as False but its going to True.

This is the typical scenario happening in production also servers are located in Pacific and users are from London. Please provide me the solutions for this problem.

```
String  vacationStartDate = "25/11/2011";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
//America/Los_Angeles
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(tz);      
Date start = dateFormatter.parse(vacationStartDate);                    
Date todayBeginning = new Date();

if ( start.before(todayBeginning)){
    System.out.println("True ");    
} else {
    System.out.println("False ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're parsing the date in the London timezone, but printing it out in your timezone. So 25/11/2011 00:00:00 in London is 24/11/2011 16:00:00 or whatever in your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the current date of your Timezone, so the output is correct. Please note that the `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");` is the timezone of the **Date being parsed** so the date returned given that your current timezone is *Pacific* will be before the London date.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Date in Different Time zone even though i have different timezone set in my local.

Comment: You can change your default locale

Answer (score 0):

A date (day/month/year) is a fundamentally different concept than a instant of time (when we say "vacations start on 25/11/2011" we are not meaning "25/11/2011 at 00:00:00", we are refering to that day as a whole entity). It's a disgrace that the standard Java API (as many others) confuses this concepts, and your problem (explained in Matthew Farwell's answer) is one of the many absurd issues that this confusion causes: one should not need to deal with timezones issues when doing pure dates calculation.

Consider using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has an specific class ([Localdate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)) for pure dates.

Comment: my exact requirement is for example i set my machine to PST time zone and i want to identify the exact date in IST or EST without considering the local timezone i have set in my machine. Here what is happening is its taking the PST time from there its calculating the IST or EST. This is my problem and i cant use joda in my project.